# MigLayout - Server browser

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane, miglayout

I have a question for those of you who are familiar with MigLayout or basically Swing usage.

I am trying to create a server browser for a game.

The layout will end up looking like the following below. Also, I honestly don't know what layout manager to use.

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+-------------------+---+-----+
|  tab1   |  tab2   |  tab3   |  tab4   |  tab5   |  tab6   |  tab7   |                   | X |     |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+                   +---+     |
|                                                                                                   |             
+-----------+--------------------+---------+-----------+                                            |  
| Country   | Servers            | Players | Game mode |                                            |
+-----------+--------------------+---------+-----------+                                            |
|           |                    |         |           |                                            |
|           |                    |         |           |                                            |
|           |                    |         |           |                                            |
|           |                    |         |           |                                            |
|           |                    |         |           |                                            |
|           |                    |         |           |                                            |
|           |                    |         |           |                                            |
|           |                    |         |           |                                            |
+-----------+--------------------+---------+-----------+                                            |
|                                                                                                   |
|                                                                                                   |
|                          +---------------+                                                        |
|                          |   Username    |                                                        |
|                          +---------------+                                                        |
|                                                                                                   |
|                                     +-------------+     +-------------+                           |
|                                     |  Spectate   |     |    Play     |                           |
|                                     +-------------+     +-------------+                           |
|                                                                                                   |
|                                                                                                   |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

When the window is resized, all the components should fill the x-axis. Like a dynamically panel with a dynamic TabbedPane.

Here is my code so far:

```
/**
 * A class handling the server browser.
 * @author Jamie
 */
 public class ServerBrowser extends JPanel {

/**
 * Handle the server browser from client.
 * @param c The client reference in case it was used in-game.
 * @param m The main reference in case it was used in-game.
 * TODO @return reference
 */
public Client c;
public Main m;

private int width = 400;
private int height = 500;

private JTabbedPane tabbedPane;

public ServerBrowser(Main m, Client c) {
    this.m = m;
    this.c = c;

    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    this.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.GRAY, 1, true));

   // Creating the object and template
   tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
   this.add(tabbedPane);

   /**
    * Handle the tabs from the tabbed pane.              
    */
   JPanel internetTab = new JPanel();
   JPanel customTab = new JPanel();
   JPanel favoritesTab = new JPanel();
   JPanel historyTab = new JPanel();
   JPanel spectateTab = new JPanel();
   JPanel lanTab = new JPanel();
   JPanel friendsTab = new JPanel();

   // Creates the label to go in each of the tabs
   JLabel label1 = new JLabel(); 
   JLabel label2 = new JLabel();
   JLabel label3 = new JLabel();
   JLabel label4 = new JLabel();
   JLabel label5 = new JLabel();
   JLabel label6 = new JLabel();
   JLabel label7 = new JLabel();

   //Set the text of each of the labels in the tabbed panes.
   label1.setText("This tab will display a list of all the servers.");
   label2.setText("What should this tab display?");
   label3.setText("What should this tab display?");
   label4.setText("What should this tab display?");
   label5.setText("What should this tab display?");
   label6.setText("What should this tab display?");
   label7.setText("What should this tab display?");

   //Add the labels to the specific tabs
   internetTab.add(label1);
   customTab.add(label2);
   favoritesTab.add(label3);
   historyTab.add(label4);
   spectateTab.add(label5);
   lanTab.add(label6);
   friendsTab.add(label7);

   // Create test JTextArea and place at certain x,y coordinate
   JTextArea unText1 = new JTextArea();
   internetTab.add(unText1);
   unText1.setBounds(200,200,150,50);

   // Name the tabs and add them into the Tabbed Pane object
   tabbedPane.addTab("            Internet            ", internetTab);
   tabbedPane.addTab("            Custom            ", customTab);
   tabbedPane.addTab("            Favorites            ", favoritesTab);
   tabbedPane.addTab("            History            ", historyTab);
   tabbedPane.addTab("            Spectate            ", spectateTab);
   tabbedPane.addTab("            Lan            ", lanTab);
   tabbedPane.addTab("            Friends            ", friendsTab);

   // Buttons
   JButton test = new JButton("Press");
   customTab.add(test);

   // Action listener
   ButtonHandler phandler = new ButtonHandler();
   test.addActionListener(phandler);



   this.setVisible(true);



public void handleResize() {
    // Center
    //int x = (m.getWidth() - width) / 2;
    int x = m.getWidth() - width - 25;
    int y = (m.getHeight() - height - m.mb.getHeight()) / 3;
    this.setBounds(x,y,width,height);   
}
```

I have spent hours and hours figuring out a solution to how I can achive a server browser like this one, but I haven't succeed yet.. What I want is to make a server browser similar to the one below
[image]

How would you achieve this?

Comment: If you use eclipse you can choose and install this plugin :  https://eclipse.org/windowbuilder/. This is a perfect tool to configure and see your GUI during the coding-process. It supports the Mig-Layout too.

Comment: I am using Eclipse. Personally, I don't prefer using the WindowBuilder plugin, mainly because that in my opinion it's not as user friendly as one might think.

Comment: I support your opinion. But i used this builder for my last project (based on a complex GUI) and my expreinec is very well with this tool.

Comment: If you can give me a few decent references on how I can use the plugin properly in order to achive what I want; I'll happily give it a shot. I have spent hours and days trying to figure this case out. I honestly don't know where to start.

Comment: I would stay away from Mig-layout because it is a pain to manage.

Comment: Milez, I'll tell you what: Please look above for the updated class handling my server browser - only that code is a pain to manage. And that's only for the tabbed pane.

Comment: 1.) install the feature 2.) click on New -> Other ->WindowsBuilder -> SwingDesigner -> JPanel/JFrame (what u want) and you will get a Code and a Layout tab. 3.) Switch with drag and drop to miglayout and start to drag and drop your items.

Comment: I am not going to use the WindowBuilder tool in Eclipse. I want to figure this out the correct way.

Answer (score 1):

Use as many JPanels as You need. I would use here at least 2 or 3. First for label and tabbedpane and second (and third) for the rest. 
Here' s an example of how first could be managed:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

public class App {

    public static void launchView(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Game");
        JLabel servers = new JLabel("Servers");
        Object [][] data = {{"A","B","C","D"}, {"E","F","G","H"}};  //add more components to see the effect
        String [] columnNames = {"Servers", "Game", "Players", "Map"};
        JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames);    //or proper JTabbedPane

        frame.setLayout(new MigLayout());
        frame.add(servers, "pos 0% 5% 30% 10%");
        frame.add(new JScrollPane(table), "pos 0% 20% 100% 100%");

        frame.setSize(new Dimension(500, 400));
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String [] args){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                launchView();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

But of course, in Mig usually there are more than one way to do the thing. 
If You would still have problem with managing other components, please tell me

Comment: You mean the example code ? If yes, what compiler error are You getting ? Also, I believe the logic is good and in fact You could accomplish all Your view using just this method and many JPanels (which doesn' t mean this would be most efficient).